# Trying to download a matplotlib module from cached data but it's not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

**[image: original_terminal]**

So basically I don't know how to use pyenv so i just download modules directly. This time I was trying to install matplotlib when I interrupted the process by CTRL-C since it was just showing the progress bar at full but doing nothing.
Then I tried to install again, with pip3 install matplotlib.py.
It ran the cached-matplotlib. Then this happened.
I've tried uninstalling it but it doesn't exist, I've also tried restarting my laptop but it didn't do anything.
I've searched online for the past 1 hour now and no answer at all.
If there's really no way then I guess I'll trying using pyenv(that's what it's for right?).
(I use pip3 because my default built-in python is python2)
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using python 3.9 version. According to [matplotlib](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/) 3.3.3 the pip command doesn’t support this version yet as of today. So, downgrade your python version to 3.8 may solve the issue. Also, using pyenv to manage your python version would save you those issues in the future.

Comment: so i don't need to worry about the installing thingy seen from the image?